# Guice and generic factory

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm new to guice, and using guice 4.1 I want to instantiate the following class:

```
public class GuiceMain<T> implements IGuiceMain<T> {

    private ObjectWrapperFactory<T> factory;

    @Inject
    public GuiceMain(ObjectWrapperFactory<T> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void process(T t) {
        ObjectWrapper wrapper = factory.create(t);
    }
}
```

I dont have strong requirements how to create it, but I came to the solution to create interface GuiceMainFactory

```
public interface GuiceMainFactory {
    <T> GuiceMain<T> create();
}
```

so my client code will look like this:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new Configuration());
GuiceMain<File> instance = injector.getInstance(GuiceMainFactory.class).create();
File f = new File("text.txt");

instance.process(f);
```

and in my guice configuration class I write

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().implement(IGuiceMain.class, GuiceMain.class).build(GuiceMainFactory.class))
```

But I get the error: **1) com.guice.GuiceMainFactory cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.**
So I decided to write the implementation of GuiceMainFactory

```
public class GuiceMainFactoryImpl implements GuiceMainFactory {

    private ObjectWrapperFactory objectWrapperFactory;

    @Inject
    public GuiceMainFactoryImpl(ObjectWrapperFactory objectWrapperFactory) {
        this.objectWrapperFactory = objectWrapperFactory;
    }

    @Override 
    public <T> GuiceMain<T> create() {
        return new GuiceMain<T>(objectWrapperFactory);
    }
}
```

but in this case, on the line *return new GuiceMain(objectWrapperFactory);* I get *unchecked assignment* warning, because I cant specify generic type of objectWrapperFactory

I think I've over complicated everything, but I dont know how to deal with it

Comment: This is fundamentally not type-safe, in a way that isn't really related to Guice.

Comment: Can you push the type variable in `ObjectWrapperFactory<T>` onto the `create` method instead?

Comment: @AndyTurner I can, but if I do it - guice will not instantiate ObjectWrapperFactory<T> for me.